# Android Gradle error while importing old project

Tags: android, gradle

I am importing one project which was created by another person a long time ago. And when I import I get these errors which I resolved but now I am stuck with this below error while syncing app Gradle file which I don't know how to resolve.

My build.gradle (app module)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/donnfelker/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.co.blab"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi"
    }
}
```

What shall i do.

below is error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Try to clean and build your project

Comment: I did clean and build the project

Comment: try changing targetSdkVersion  25

Comment: Yes, I did. Still same error.

Comment: You have any images in res folders? Check the names of images named within  [a-z0-9_.]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` to same version. Change them to version **25**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.co.blab"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ...
    }
}
```

In case you're using Android Studio >= 3.0, change you build gradle tools to version `3.0.1` (you better move this to your **project** build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

and update your gradle inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` to `gradle-4.1-all.zip`.

Last, move the following line to the end of your app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```